# In Drupal, how do you create more events in the events dropdown of the Triggered Rules?

Tags: events, drupal, drupal-rules

In Drupal, how do you create more events in the events dropdown of the Triggered Rules? I'm not sure if I'm supposed to create a new trigger, a new action, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom module that implements hook_rules_event_info(). There's more detail in the documentation on [Adding new events](http://drupal.org/node/298549).

Comment: Thanks. I found this info after some digging and got it to work.